# Custom Font issue in DomPDF latest version 0.8.2

Tags: php, css, fonts, dompdf

I am using composer installation of DomPDF. so i can't use custom font. I have used font-face option but font is not applying in PDF.

```
$dompdfOptions->set('fontDir', CSSPATH);// for default fonts
$dompdfOptions->set('fontDir', FONTSPATH);// for custom fonts
$dompdfOptions->set('defaultMediaType', 'all');
$dompdfOptions->set('isFontSubsettingEnabled', true);
$dompdf = new Dompdf($dompdfOptions);
```

but font is not apply.

if i following style:

```
"font-family: Georgia;" // Georgia is example
```

not working but if i use

```
"font: 24px Georgia;"
```

font is working but if i add font styles like italic/bold, again it is not working.

Please let me know what is issue in this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have created demo to use `Custom Fonts` in `DomPDF`.

```
<?php
$html = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <title>DUMMY DOM PDF</title>
    <style>        
        @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Joti+One");
        .joti-font {font-family: "Joti One", cursive;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="joti-font">This is Test PDF</div>
</body>
</html>';

require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

use Dompdf\Dompdf;

$dompdf = new Dompdf();

$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("codex",array("Attachment"=>0));
?>
```

[image]

Comment: I want to use custom fonts, not default one!!

Comment: 1.load_font file is not part of new version and 2. it is updating core directory of DOMPDF. I am not sure but it is not good idea to update core directory while using composer. So i tried second option font-face but it is not woking

Comment: Have you tried by applying external css to that PDF? This link is helpful to you. https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1208

Comment: I have tried but not working :( can you create demo?

Comment: same code is not working while i am generating PDF. Font is not applying. Which DomPDF version you have used?

Comment: I am using Dompdf 0.8.2(latest) and font is also applying on it.

Comment: I am using same latest version but it is not woking

Comment: Okay, i gave write permission to fonts/ directory and it is working. Same code will work with composer based code?

Comment: if i change your style to  .joti-font {font-family: "Joti One", cursive;font-size:40px;font-style:italic;}, it is not working

Comment: I have used random fonts from Google Fonts for demo purpose. You can use your own and all font's css depended on the fonts you have chosen. If should check it's doc.

Comment: but font-style is not applying well while creating pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

Use css and it worked. we need to use font instead of font-family in css.

```css
@font-face{
font-family: myFontName;
src:url('http:://yourwebsite.com/myFontName.ttf');
}
p{
font: myFontName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your custom font issue, [mpdf](https://mpdf.github.io/) is better than DomPDF and others. it has following features

1. [add new fonts](https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/fonts-in-mpdf-7-x.html#easy-to-add-new-fonts)
2. Full Unicode support
3. Complex scripts support
   3.1 Right-to-left languages (Hebrew, Arabic etc.)Permalink
   3.2 Indic languages, Lao, Tibetan etc
   3.3 Vertical writing
4. TrueType Collections
5. Unicode Supplementary Planes

How to add new fonts with mpdf

1. Add your font directory to fontDir configuration parameter or by
   calling $mpdf->AddFontDirectory() method
2. Define the font file details in the fontData parameter array
3. Access the font by specifying it in your HTML code as the CSS
   font-family
4. Specifying languages for the font by defining custom
   Mpdf\Language\LanguageToFontInterface and
   Mpdf\Language\ScriptToLanguage implementation